# Admin Logged In Validation - Front End Opencart

Tags: opencart

Is there any way to check if the admin is logged in at front-end in `Opencart`? I would like to show a notice bar with content "Admin Logged In" when I open my store.

To be precise, in the controller of my module, i would like to add:

```
$data['admin_logged'] = some_function;
```

and when I echo it in my `.tpl` to get `1` if admin is logged in or `0` if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i got it done by:

```
// Check if admin is logged in - frontend
$this->user = new User($this->registry);
$data['admin_logged']=($this->user->isLogged())
```

Now you can use if($admin_logged) /* do stuff here */

Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check it, using the `User` class:

```
$data['admin_logged'] = $this->user->isLogged() ? 1 : 0;
```